# Can't change leaflet setView params when using leaflet-headless

Tags: node.js, canvas, leaflet

I need to generate a map on the server side using Nodejs and then create an image of that map. I'm using [leaflet-headless](https://github.com/jieter/leaflet-headless)  to create the map and generate the image.

This is the code:

```
const L = require('leaflet-headless');
const document = global.document;
let createMap = (lanLat) => {
        const element = document.createElement('div');
        element.id = 'map-leaflet-image';
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        const filename = path.join(__dirname, '/leaflet-image.png');
        const map = L.map(element.id).setView([0, 0], 3);

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        map.saveImage(filename, () => {
            console.log('done');
        })
};
```

This works and the image is saved but when I change the `setView()` parameters to `setView([0,0], 1)`(zoom out) I receive an error message:

> return prev.apply(ctx, arguments);
>
> Error: Image given has not completed loading
>
> at Error (native)
>       at CanvasRenderingContext2D.ctx.(anonymous function) [as drawImage]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this might interest someone, the problem was in the `map.save()` function which uses the leaflet-image lib.

This happened due to a weirdly specific scenario where a marker with certain coordinates, when added to the map  with any other marker(?!), caused the error. I removed that marker and it worked.